# How to split column value to columns SQL via select statement

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
ID   COACODE
-------------------
1    10200001
```

I want select statement split it like

```
ID   BR  DEPT  MINS
-------------------
1    10  2000  01
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: `SUBSTRING()` function will help you if column length in table is fixed

Comment: See if this helps (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202408/to-split-numbers-using-sql-server)

Comment: SELECT  SUBSTRING(COACODE, 1, 2) as BR ,  SUBSTRING(COACODE, 3, 6) as DEPT , SUBSTRING(COACODE, 7, 8) as MINS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [SUBSTRING()](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/substring.php)

The SUBSTRING functions allows you to extract a substring from a string.

NOTE: its works on when each row have same length of value otherwise it makes error

```
SELECT ID,SUBSTRING(COACODE, 1, 2) as BR , SUBSTRING(COACODE, 3, 6) as DEPT , SUBSTRING(COACODE, 7, 8) as MINS from table_name
```